# Use value of attribute as content of element

Tags: javascript, html, regex

**What I'm looking for**

I have code like this:

`<div this-html="text goes here"></div>`

After a regex, I want the value of attribute "this-html" be the text between the opening and closing tag, like so:

`<div>text goes here</div>`

The element can contain other attributes and doesn't have to be a div, it can basically be any other type of element, as long as it uses a closing tag (which doesn't have to be on the same line). It's also possible that the input has text between the tags, like so `<div this-html="text goes here">dummy text</div>`, but that can be ignored / should be overwritten with the value of the "this-html" attribute.

**What I have**

I can't use jQuery or turn the string into a Javascript object, as it may contain PHP (which will then get crippled if you turn it back into a string again). This script is used during a 'publish to html' process of an application, hence it can contain PHP. And so, I'm trying to solve it using regular expressions.

So basically, all I have is Javascript and the HTML I need to work with is just a string, there's no DOM to work with.

Now, I have a regular expression that does this for me, but it doesn't work when you have multiple matches on the same line or when I have another attribute after "this-html".

This is the regex I'm using:
`/(<\s*[^<]+?)this-html=['"]{1}(.+)['"]{1}([^>]*>)[\w\W]*?(<\/.+>)/gmi`

And I group it back together with `$1$3$2$4`.

Now, let's say I have the following input:
`<div this-html="text goes here!" class="something">test</div><div this-html="another test">Option is visible on preview/publish</div>`

Then my regex pattern will mess this up and I end up with something like this:
`<div >text goes here!" class="something">test</div><div this-html="another test</div>`

I'm not a regex guru, but I get the feeling this regex could be a whole lot simpler, but I'm stuck here.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. [regex is not suitable to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5734311) 2. you don't have to do string composing for tasks like this; an HTML document is parsed into the DOM 3. use `element.innerHTML = element.getAttribute('this-html')` 4. please clarify what you by "may contain PHP"

Comment: @ChrisG, I edited my post a little. I'm using this in a 'publish-to-html' process in an application. Javascript is available there, but the HTML I need to work with is just a string there, there's no DOM.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/fQtnmo/2, `text.replace(/(<\s*(\w+)[^<]*?)\s+this-html=['"]([^"']*)['"]([^>]*?)\s*>[\w\W]*?(<\/\2>)/gi, '$1$4>$3$5')`

Comment: You can create a virtual DOM based on the string, run the code on the elements, then turn the result back to HTML.

Comment: You might want to look at templating systems, e.g. handlbars or pug or twig.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes! This seems to work really well for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't use that, seriously. Use this: https://jsfiddle.net/jymr20gp/

Comment: @ChrisG I have tried that (and I'd prefer that!), but the string of HTML can contain PHP. If you put that entire string into a DOM object and (once done) back into a string, the PHP tags are crippled and I'd have to fix that up again. It's a world of pain.

Comment: That's true, who designed this system...!? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way of doing what you want:

```js
function convert(html) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = html;
  div.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(el => {
    var h = el.getAttribute('this-html');
    if (h) {
      el.innerHTML = h;
      el.removeAttribute('this-html');
    }
  });
  return div.innerHTML;
}


var html = '<div this-html="text goes here!" class="something">test</div><div this-html="another test">Option is visible on preview/publish</div>';

console.log( convert(html) );
```

However, as your environment does not allow you to use DOM, you might resort to regex like

```js
text.replace(/(<\s*(\w+)[^<]*?)\s+this-html=['"]([^"']*)['"]([^>]*?)\s*>[\w\W]*?(<\/\2>)/gi, '$1$4>$3$5')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fQtnmo/2). **NOTE**: once it is possible to use DOM, please switch to the solution, and not this workaround.

*Details*

- `(<\s*(\w+)[^<]*?)` - Group 1 (`$1` value): `<`, zero or more whitespaces, Group 2 (`$2` value): any one or more word chars, then any zero or more chars other than `<` as few as possible
- `\s+` - one or more whitespace
- `this-html=` - literal text
- `['"]` - a `"` or `'`
- `([^"']*)` - Group 3 (`$3` value): zero or more chars other than `"` and `'`
- `['"]` - a `"` or `'`
- `([^>]*?)` - Group 4 (`$4` value): any zero or more chars other than `>` as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace
- `>` - a `>` char
- `[\w\W]*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `(<\/\2>)` - Group 5 (`$5` value): `</`, same value as in Group 2, `>`.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
var text = '<div this-html="text goes here!" class="something">test</div><div this-html="another test">Option is visible on preview/publish</div>';
console.log( text.replace(/(<\s*(\w+)[^<]*?)\s+this-html=['"]([^"']*)['"]([^>]*?)\s*>[\w\W]*?(<\/\2>)/gi, '$1$4>$3$5') );
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer, it's much appreciated!

Until I get the chance to implement a proper solution, this will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the PHP code contained in the string will look like, but can something like this be fine? :)

```js
var regex = /<\s*(\w+)([^>]*)\s*this-html=\"([^"]*)\"([^>]*)>[^<]*<\s*\/\s*\w+\s*>/gi;
var stringTest = '<div this-html="text goes here!" class="something">test</div><div this-html="another test">Option is visible on preview/publish</div>';
var result = stringTest.replace(regex,'<$1$2$4>$3</$1>');
alert(result);
```